Should I use 'Stop' or 'Pause' to suspend a Grsync process before shutting down my computer?
I am currently using GRsync to copy the contents of one 10TB drive to another drive. I'm letting the process run overnight, but I'll need to suspend it in the morning and shut off my laptop so that I can take my computer to work.
I see that GRsync has both 'Pause' and 'Stop' commands. Which would be the best one to use--or would it not make a difference in this case? Would either choice cause me to lose the progress this backup has made so far?
(Also, in case it's relevant, I didn't enable the 'partial' option beforehand, so I think it will need to restart the last file it was copying from scratch. This shouldn't be an issue, though, as most of my files are relatively small in size.)
